# Translate strings not recognised in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, translation

I am trying to translate my plugin strings, but for some reason my plugin does not find the strings via the _e() and __() functions.

My plugin directory is called test-plugin.

My plugin `/test-plugin/test-plugin.php` files looks as follows:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test plugin
Version: 1.0
Author: Robbert Vermeulen
License: GPL2
Text Domain: test-plugin
*/

_e( 'This is a test text', 'test-plugin' );
__( 'This is another test text', 'test-plugin' )


function test_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'test-plugin', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'test_plugin_load_plugin_textdomain' );

?>
```

When I try to sync the strings the plugin only finds the values from my plugin description to translate.

[image]

What do I have to do so that the strings are recognized?

My test-plugin.pot file looks like:

```
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Test plugin\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2018-11-13 16:16+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: \n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Loco https://localise.biz/"

#. Author of the plugin
msgid "Robbert Vermeulen"
msgstr ""

#. Name of the plugin
msgid "Test plugin"
msgstr ""
```

Comment: Have you actually updated your plugin's POT file (`languages/test-plugin.pot`)? It should contain something like `msgid "This is a test text"`. Or you haven't created that file..?

Comment: @SallyCJ checkout my pot file in my question. The problem is that there are no strings other than the ones from the plugin description synced.

Comment: You need to update your POT file so that it contains those new translatable strings. They're *not* automatically added to the file.

Comment: @SallyCJ but a plugin like this https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/ can sync those strings. I also works for my theme but not for my plugin..

Comment: @SallyCJ I already did the test with `__( 'This is another test text', 'test-plugin' )` and no results. Local translate says: "Extraction of translatable strings from your source code" and it does it with my theme, but not with my plugin.

Comment: I just found how the plugin works. I need to update the template (.pot) file each time and then sync the language.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes, but this plugin can extract the strings from the templates, but you need it needs an extra action only. So first sync the .pot file and then sync the language specific file.

Comment: Yep, you're so right. +1 again for that, and +1 also for the helpful question! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to update the template (.pot) file each time and then sync the language.